# Hide internal classes of a library

Tags: android, android-architecture

When developing an android library, is it possible to hide internal classes so they're not available for the one who uses the library?

Suppose there is a module `sdk`. Let's suppose that someone develops an application and relies on the `sdk`.

`sdk` provides an interface (let's say `X` and it's implementation `XImpl`) and then has a lot of internal classes that are used to implement the `XImpl`.

How to hide the classes so the user of a library sees only `X`, `XImpl` (and possibly it's parameters)?

I distribute the `sdk` via a Gradle repository, so I can work with the modules a bit and extract that, but in the best case, I'd like to achieve that with some ProGuard configuration or similar.

Comment: Just set the visibility of your classes to something different than public.

Comment: Well, I'd like to leave the code as is and e.g. declare that package "internal" is not visible outside the library project. Moreover, if you declare classes e.g. protected, then you won't see them from outside the package.